# Outbound Email in Tridion 2009

Tags: 2009, outbound-email

As I understand Outbound Email does not come with Tridion default installation. I found a extension for it and it also have separate license.

Now, if license is not renewed i.e. the plugin will be removed, then I guess the "Outbound Email within Website Management" will disappear as well. Users and audience segment are managed form there, so how discontinue of the Outbound license will affect this?

Please correct me if my understandings are wrong.

Under any publication it is appearing like the following image 
[image: OBEmail]

Please let me know, if discontinue of the license will remove the option "Outbound Email" from the publication level.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that without a license for Outbound Email you also lose access to Audience Management, as those systems are "2 faces of the same coin"

Comment: Actually - I am not sure anymore, evidence seems to suggest otherwise (2 separate license nodes). I will investigate this

Comment: Thanks Nuno, please let me know if you have anything to share on this.

Comment: Sorry, can't find a 2009 environment to test with. With 2013 and 2011 AM still works after removing the OE node from the license.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your license expires, all of the relevant functionality will silently disappear from the CME. The services will refuse to start, though, and will log the licensing exception.

There's separate licenses for Audience Manager and Outbound E-mail and each feature checks for the appropriate license. Generally speaking anything related to managing and synchronizing Contacts is part of Audience Manager and anything related to Mailings and tracking is part of Outbound E-mail.

Comment: Thanks, but the "Audience Management" is coming under the section "Outbound Email" at web publication level, so if this option goes away, where the option for "Audience Manager " (managing and synchronizing Contacts) will come. Please clarify my doubts.

Comment: The section will still be there, you will just not see Mailings and such anymore. Any data you have already created remains until such a time as you have a valid OE license again.

Comment: For what it's worth, we made this separation much clearer in later versions. AM and OE are two separate sections in the tree and elsewhere.